# Fill ListView CellTemplate is another ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I added ListView as a cellTemplate to another ListView Like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listlabel">
           <ListView AllowDrop="True" Width="Auto" ></ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListView x:Name="SequenceList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Sequence ID" Width="120"/>  
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Map Items" Width="226" CellTemplate="{StaticResource listlabel}">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Now I want to add items to Parent ListView Whic Contain two columns

> "Sequence ID" && "Map Items"

How I can add items?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new ListView Items by doing something close to this

ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new []{"1","2","3","4"}); fill it in with what ever you want to add within your example

Comment: Use that as an example to fit your case.. I was using that to show you as an example..